# What can I do after my account is gone?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I logged in this morning, and instead of logging in, it asked me to join the community through stack exchange again, and now I am at 101 reputation, instead of the 360 I was at yesterday. How can I get my reputation, questions, and answers back?

Answer (score 9):

You've already been contacted about this directly.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)